# EasyAdmin 3.x display OneToMany realtion on details page

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, easyadmin

on easyadmin 3.4 and symfony 5.4 I have the following 2 entities: Event, Participant, where an Event can have many participants.

I created a details page for the events on the controller's `configureActions()` method using `$actions->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL)`. What i want to achieve is displaying the list of participants on the event details page, as they are displayed on the participants index page (paginated table, having a search button, etc). I would prefer doing it without creating custom templates and only by configurations/what the framework provides, as long as it is possible.

What i tried by now is using the `CollectionField` and `AssociationField` on the `configureFields()` method, but i only managed to display the participants separated via coma (by overriding the `__toString()` method) and I also tried playing around with the actions on the `configureActions()` method.

Thank you in advance for any possible solution!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.